# React, is it absoluately necessary to treat react state as immutable?

Tags: reactjs, immutability

I'm doing something like this and wonder if it should be avoided at all, or acceptable.

Because it's just complex to treat state as immutable..

The first version is what I usually do

```
render() {
  var { blogs } = this.state
  var blogNodes = blogs.map((blog, i) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {blog.name}
        <Checkbox
          checked={blog.checked}
          onChange={
            (e, {name, value, checked}) => {
              blog.checked = checked
              this.setState({blogs})
            }
          }
          />
      </div>
    )
    })                                                                                                                                                                                   
} ,
```

And this second version seems to be the more correct version of doing it

```
render() {
  var { blogs } = this.state                                                                                                                                                       
  var blogNodes = blogs.map((blog, i) => {                                                                                                                                          

  return (                                                                                                                                                                          
     <div>
        {blog.name}
        <Checkbox
          checked={blog.checked}
          onChange={
            (e, {name, value, checked}) => {
              blog.checked = checked
              var newState = update(this.state, {
                blogs: {
                  i: {
                    $set: {
                      checked: checked
                    }
                  }
                }
              })
              this.setState(newState)
            }
          }
          />
      </div>
    )
  })
}
```

Is it absolutely neccessary to treat react state as immutable or it's just for performance reasons?

If I have to treat it immutable, is there a simpler way of doing the above than my 2nd version? 
It would be more tiresome when we have the index(i) available at hand.

Comment: The second is wrong also, you're still setting `blog.checked` to true. And yes, the state must be immutable, otherwise there will be problems. And also don't put the code inline in the render, make it into a function and it'll be easier to handle at least. Simpler otherwise? That's a bit more a matter of opinion also.

Comment: Immutability makes sense if you are using a state handler like redux, because it provides debugging tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it absolutely neccessary to treat react state as immutable?

Depends on what you mean by "absolutely necessary", but I think it's safe to say that it's a *really bad idea* to mutate state in React if [the authors straight up tell you it's "wrong"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). You are going to shoot yourself in the foot if you keep doing it. Performance tuning is one reason, but another reason is simply that you will get unpredictable behavior if you don't follow React's API rules, such as unintentionally overwriting data or breaking rendering in hard-to-debug ways.

React is all about a predictable rendering cycle: use `setState()` to make change to state, which triggers a `render()` at some point in the future with the latest state.

Your second example still has issues. First, you're still mutating `blog` in state by setting `blog.checked = true`. Second, you are replacing the *entire* state with `newState`. That's a recipe for problems, because `setState()` only *schedules* a patch, so you should only replace the prop(s) that you are actually changing -- `setState({blogs})` in your case -- or you might conflict with other calls to `setState()`. Lastly, if you are accessing the current `state` you should really use the callback form ([second example](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)) to ensure the state you are working from is in fact the fully up-to-date version.

Using ES6 object spread you could do it this way:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  const {blogs} = this.state;
  return {
    blogs: [
      ...blogs.slice(0, i), 
      { ...blogs[i], selected: true }
      ...blogs.slice(i)
    ]
  };
});
```

Or using `map()` to just replace one element by index:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  const {blogs} = this.state;
  return {
    blogs: blogs.map(
      (blog, index) => index == i ? { ...blog, selected: true } : blog
    )
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it ABSOLUTELY necessary to keep your components state immutable? No, but it is important to understand why you should, specially if you have nesting inside your state tree (like your example), here are the reasons

React updates a component when ever state (or props) of the said component updates, and the best part about react is you can have TOTAL control over when this update should occur using shouldComponentUpdate() life cycle event, So.. if you are mutating your state object, then you will have to do something which is known as *deep equity checks* to figure out when the state is updated, which will get worse as your state object has more nesting inside,.

Now imagine keeping your state as immutable objects, and you end up with this beautiful state object which is explicit and easily predictable, and you can optimize you component accordingly for better performance...

Secondly, react by default dont do deep equity checks to see if state or props are updated, so you may hear them telling people not to mutate the state, like others have mentioned,

Now for implementing any react component, always remember that, keeping your state minimal is the best React practice you can acquire, so it is always better to give components only those values which are require for it to render.

```
onChange(event, i) {
 const target = event.target;
 const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
 this.props.handleChange(this.props.blog, value)
}

render() {
  var { blog } = this.state                                                                                                                                                       
  return (                                                                                                                                                                          
     <div>
        {blog.name}
        <Checkbox
          checked={blog.checked}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          />
      </div>
    )
}
```

and then in your parent blogs component

```
handleChange(blog, value) {
 this.setState({
   blogs: [
    ...blogs,
    {...blog,  selected: value}
   ]
 })
}
```

Comment: Second example is going to append a new blog, not replace an existing one. Check my answer.